# Formula to get the value from another table column

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have two tables T1 (columns id, a,b,c) and T2 (columns id, d,e,f) with a common key id, and a 1:1 relation, and with POwerQuery I would like to create a new column in T2 which name will be 'g' and value will be True if T1.c is not blank/null, and False otherwise. All columns are text except id.

The formulas I wrote in PowerQuery advanced editor of table T2 are:

```
#"Step" = Table.AddColumn(T2, "g", each if T1[c]<>null then Logical.FromText("true") else Logical.FromText("false"), type logical)
```

Result is True in the whole new 'g' column

or with other formula:

```
#"Step" = Table.AddColumn(T2, "g", each if Text.Length(T1[c])>0 then Logical.FromText("true") else Logical.FromText("false"), type logical)
```

Result is 'Error' (in yellowish color) in the whole 'g' column

other test:

```
#"Step" = Table.AddColumn(T2, "g", each if T1[c]{0}, type text)
```

Result is: first line text in the whole column.

What is wrong and how to be able to get True if the T1.c is not null/empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the rows are exactly lined up between tables, try this

```
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(T2, "Index", 0, 1),
#"Step" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "g", each each Table1{[Index]}[c] <> null and Table1{[Index]}[c] <> "", type logical)
```

If they are not lined up, you should merge one table into the other on the common key, expand, then create a custom column to test

```
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(T2,{"Key"},T1,{"Key"},"Table1",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table1", {"c"}, {"c"}),
#"Step" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Table1", "g", each [c] <> null and [c] <> "", type logical)
```

edited based on below comment

Comment: The second one is interesting, as I have 2 different tables, different size but common key if the record exists. Is the "= null" test handling empty/blank data also ?

Comment: The second option looks good here except that empty and blank both need to be handled for text columns since `null <> ""`. It may be simpler to skip the `if`/`then` syntax and just write `each [c] <> null and [c] <> ""` or `each Text.Length([c]) > 0`.

Comment: Thanks, that code seems to work fine, and I added the null and "" cases.

Answer (score 1):

Table[ColumnName] will always return a list of all values in the column. Even an empty list is different from null. That's why your first example is `true` for all in the column.

Text.Length(list) will always return an error because it expects text.

You'll need to join your tables together. If they are already separate queries, you're in luck, no code knowledge needed.

Then expand the "joined column" column by clicking on the little widget on the right end of the column titles.

Now you've got one big table and can go from there. Horseyride has the right idea.

Comment: isn't the "each" keyword there to split the column/list data and handle them one element by one ?

Comment: Okay, first, realize that functions (whether built-in functions or ones you make) can themselves be stored in variables and passed around as arguments. Table.AddColmn, for example, uses the function you provide and passes each record (i.e. row) into it, using the output as the new column's value. `each` turns whatever's after it into a function that takes a single argument named `_` so, really, `each [x]` is a more readable equivalent of `(_) => [x]` (power query assumes that by `[x]` you really mean `_[x]`), so the function `each [x]` is the same as the function `(r as record) => r[x]`!

Comment: It's mind-bending, I know. Likewise, given `f = (myFunction) => List.Transform(T1[c], myFunction)`, the following are equivalent: `f( (t) => Text.Upper(t) )`, `f(each Text.Upper(_))`, or even `f(Text.Upper)` because Text.Upper is *already* a function that takes a single argument!

Comment: If you know JavaScript, consider how power-query's List.Transform and List.Select are analogous to JavaScript's Array.prototype.map and Array.prototype.filter